# Recursively Add Elements To Array Based on Length

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to create a recursive function that will return a list of strings representing every attribute for a given schema. It must merge this with the attributes for a given document, to include elements for each time an array element occurs in the document.

For example. If you run the following code, I expect the result to include `friends.1.addresses.1.country`. However it does not. I think this is due to the fact that it's not recursively including all the array element possibilities. Since only `0` is set for the other array possibilities in the `parentKey` & `postKey` variables.

Any ideas how to fix this?

```js
const schemaAttributes = [
 'id',
 'friends',
 'friends.0',
 'friends.0.name',
 'friends.0.addresses',
 'friends.0.addresses.0',
 'friends.0.addresses.0.country',
 'friends.0.addresses.0.zip'
];
const myDocument = {
 "id": 1,
 "friends": [
  {
   "name": "Bob",
   "addresses": [
    {"country": "world"}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Tim",
   "addresses": [
    {"country": "moon"},
    {"zip": 12345}
   ]
  }
 ]
};
console.log(main()); // Should print `friends.1.addresses.1.country` as one of the elements in the array but does not.

function main() {
 const result = schemaAttributes.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  accumulator.push(currentValue);

  const attributeParts = currentValue.split(".");

  attributeParts.forEach((a, index) => {
   const isLastPartNumber = !isNaN(parseInt(a));

   if (isLastPartNumber) {
    const parentKey = attributeParts.slice(0, index).join(".");
    const postKey = attributeParts.slice(index + 1).join(".");
    const numberOfItems = get(myDocument, parentKey).length;
    for (let i = 1; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
     accumulator.push([parentKey, i, postKey].filter((a) => Boolean(a)).join("."));
    }
   }
  });

  return accumulator;
 }, []);
 return [...new Set(result)];
}

function get(object, key) {
 const keyParts = key.split(".");
 let returnValue = object;
 keyParts.forEach((part) => {
  if (returnValue) {
   returnValue = returnValue[part];
  }
 });
 return returnValue;
}
```

---

Expected Result (order does not matter):

```
[
    "id",
    "friends",
    "friends.0",
    "friends.1",
    "friends.0.name",
    "friends.1.name",
    "friends.0.addresses",
    "friends.1.addresses",
    "friends.0.addresses.0",
    "friends.1.addresses.0",
    "friends.1.addresses.1",
    "friends.0.addresses.0.country",
    "friends.1.addresses.0.country",
    "friends.1.addresses.1.country",
    "friends.0.addresses.0.zip",
    "friends.1.addresses.0.zip",
    "friends.1.addresses.1.zip"
]
```

Comment: What is the **exact** expected result from running this?

Comment: @goto1 Just updated the original post to add what I'm aiming for.

Comment: @goto1 It should also expand as more elements are added to the given documents array's passed in. So it should be scalable.

Comment: You mean the `schemeAttributes`?

Comment: Besides what is the role of `myDocument`? I don't see it in your output

Comment: @goto1 Both `schemaAttributes` and `myDocument`. If you add more `friends` to `myDocument`, the output should change and it should add more elements to the output.

Comment: @Addis To get the count of elements in the array's. For example, the more elements you have in the `friends` array, the longer the output should be, to account for each element in the array.

Comment: This all works fine with just 1 array (`friends`). But the problem here is the nested array (`addresses`). It's not accounting for all the elements in that array.

Comment: where do you get multiple `zip` from and what happens to multiple `country`?

Comment: @NinaScholz All based on the schemaAttributes. `schemaAttributes` is generated from a schema object. The schema only says that `friends` is an array of objects. Each of those objects can have two properties, `name` (string) and `addresses` (an array of objects). Then each address object can have `zip` (number) or `country` (string). Although it's not shown here, in the schema it is defined that `country` attribute is a required attribute. The end goal is to use this to loop through the result, check if it's a required property, then if so check to see if it's undefined and throw an error.

Comment: I can't do that right now, because I don't know how many elements are in each array. So I'm trying to basically combine the number of elements in the array from `myDocument` with the `schemaAttributes` (which stores the schema information) to get a list of all the attributes that SHOULD or could exist in `myDocument`. Then I can loop through the result and handle things like required attributes and such.

Comment: If you had a third friends with empty adresses. Should the output include ```"friends.2.addresses.0.zip", "friends.2.addresses.0.country"``` ?

Comment: @grodzi Yes! That was not an edge case I had thought of yet. I will add that to my unit tests when I get a chance. But yes it does need to include those two items in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below traversing all paths matching your schemaAttribute, assuming a zero in your schemaAttribute is a wildcard for the position in array.

```js
const schemaAttributes = [
  'id',
  'friends',
  'friends.0',
  'friends.0.name',
  'friends.0.addresses',
  'friends.0.addresses.0',
  'friends.0.addresses.0.country',
  'friends.0.addresses.0.zip'
];
const myDocument = {
  "id": 1,
  "friends": [
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "addresses": [
        {"country": "world"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Tim",
      "addresses": [
        {"country": "moon"},
        {"zip": 12345}
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const out = new Set()
schemaAttributes.forEach(attr => {
  out.add(attr)
  traverse(myDocument, attr.split('.'), 0, [], path => out.add(path.join('.')))
})

function traverse (node, attrPath, idxAttrPath, outPath, cb) {
  if (idxAttrPath === attrPath.length) {
    return cb(outPath)
  }
  if (!node) { // can not explore further
    return
  }
  const attr = attrPath[idxAttrPath]
  if (attr === '0') {
    if (!Array.isArray(node)) { // can not explore further
      return
    }
    node.forEach((n, i) => {
      outPath.push(i)
      traverse(node[i], attrPath, idxAttrPath + 1, outPath, cb)
      outPath.pop()
    })
  } else {
    outPath.push(attr)
    traverse(node[attr], attrPath, idxAttrPath + 1, outPath, cb)
    outPath.pop()
  }
}
console.log('out', [...out].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)))
```

An alternative (in the spirit more efficient) would be to consider a trie so we don't explore every schemaAttribute from the start. A 'nice' property being that the fields are printed in order and we don't have to sort as done in the first approach (although it does not matter to you)

Note that the `traverse` function is almost identical

Note2: Notice the `cb(outPath)` done for every traversal, not only for leaves.

```js
const schemaAttributes = [
  'id',
  'friends',
  'friends.0',
  'friends.0.name',
  'friends.0.addresses',
  'friends.0.addresses.0',
  'friends.0.addresses.0.country',
  'friends.0.addresses.0.zip'
];
const myDocument = {
  "id": 1,
  "friends": [
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "addresses": [
        {"country": "world"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Tim",
      "addresses": [
        {"country": "moon"},
        {"zip": 12345}
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function f2 (schemaAttributes, doc) {
  // build a tree out of schema attributes
  const root = {}
  schemaAttributes.forEach(sa => {
    node = root
    sa.split('.').forEach(attr => {
      node[attr] = node[attr] || {}
      node = node[attr]
    })
  })
  // explore the tree
  function traverse (node, treeNode, outPath, cb) {
    cb(outPath)
    if (Object.keys(treeNode).length === 0) { // a leaf
      return // cb(outPath)
    }
    if (!node) {
      return
    }

    Object.keys(treeNode).forEach(attr => {

      if (attr === '0') {
        if (!Array.isArray(node)) { // can not explore further
          return
        }
        node.forEach((n, i) => {
          outPath.push(i)
          traverse(node[i], treeNode[attr], outPath, cb)
          outPath.pop()
        })
      } else {
        outPath.push(attr)
        traverse(node[attr], treeNode[attr], outPath, cb)
        outPath.pop()
      }
    })
  }
  const out = []
  traverse(doc, root, [], p => out.push(p.join('.')))
  return out.slice(1) // discard the empty string
}
console.log(f2(schemaAttributes, myDocument))
```

---

Regarding the presence of `friends.2.addresses.0.zip` the underlying idea is that the path to the leaf should be present even if path in the document is at some point `undefined`.

So the adaptation is to fake the path on the document so we can continue traversing it up until the tree leaf is reached

```js
const schemaAttributes = [
  'id',
  'friends',
  'friends.0',
  'friends.0.name',
  'friends.0.addresses',
  'friends.0.addresses.0',
  'friends.0.addresses.0.country',
  'friends.0.addresses.0.zip',
  'bob.moran.everywhere' // for properties as well
];
const myDocument = {
  "id": 1,
  "friends": [
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "addresses": [
        {"country": "world"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Tim",
      "addresses": [
        {"country": "moon"},
        {"zip": 12345}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Pumba",
      "addresses": [] // empty addresses! should show ..friends.2.adresses.0....
    }
  ]
};
function f3 (schemaAttributes, doc) {
  // build a tree out of schema attributes
  const root = {}
  schemaAttributes.forEach(sa => {
    node = root
    sa.split('.').forEach(attr => {
      node[attr] = node[attr] || {}
      node = node[attr]
    })
  })
  // explore the tree
  function traverse (node, treeNode, outPath, cb, virtualPath) {
    cb(outPath)
    if (Object.keys(treeNode).length === 0) { // a leaf
      return //cb(outPath)
    }

    Object.keys(treeNode).forEach(attr => {

      if (attr === '0') {
        if (!node || node.length == 0) {
          node = [{}] // fake the path for arrays
        }
        node.forEach((n, i) => {
          outPath.push(i)
          traverse(node[i], treeNode[attr], outPath, cb)
          outPath.pop()
        })
      } else {
        if (!node) { // fake the path for properties
          node = {}
        }
        outPath.push(attr)
        traverse(node[attr], treeNode[attr], outPath, cb)
        outPath.pop()
      }
    })
  }
  const out = []
  traverse(doc, root, [], p => out.push(p.join('.')))
  return out.slice(1)
}
console.log(f3(schemaAttributes, myDocument))
```

Comment: Will try this when I get a free moment today.

Comment: This looks amazing! As you asked in the comments tho that edge cases about an empty address array still needs to include `"friends.2.addresses.0", "friends.2.addresses.0.zip", "friends.2.addresses.0.country"`. I still need to look through this all line by line to understand it all. In the meantime if you have any ideas on how to achieve that last edge case as well that'd be awesome, then I can accept and up vote!

Comment: @Charlie Fish I have edited the post accordingly. I supposed you also wanted the properties to be reflected as well (example: 'bob.moran.everywhere' should be output even if the document has no such path).

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks so much!! I haven't gotten a chance yet to look through this in detail to understand it all. But one question that stands out to me. What is the purpose of the line `node = [{}] // fake the path for arrays`. It looks like from my code coverage report that is the only line that is never getting run. Is it trying to protect against an edge case that I maybe didn't consider? Or in what case would that be run?

Comment: This line should be run in case you have an empty array in your document (typically ```pumba``` in my test case). The goal is to fill in at least one element so we can continue traversing the tree

Answer (score -1):

You could use try out this piece of code:

```js
const schemaAttributes = [
 'id',
 'friends',
 'friends.0',
 'friends.0.name',
 'friends.0.addresses',
 'friends.0.addresses.0',
 'friends.0.addresses.0.country',
 'friends.0.addresses.0.zip'
];
const myDocument = {
 "id": 1,
 "friends": [
  {
   "name": "Bob",
   "addresses": [
    {"country": "world"}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Tim",
   "addresses": [
    {"country": "moon"},
    {"zip": 12345}
   ]
  }
 ]
};
main(); // Should print `friends.1.addresses.1.country` as one of the elements in the array but does not.

function extractKeysRecursively(obj) {
 const attributes = Object.keys(obj)
 return attributes
  flatMap(key =>
   typeof obj[key] === 'object'
   ? [isNaN(key) && key, ...extractKeysRecursively(obj[key],  ( ( parentKey && parentKey + '.' ) || '' ) + key )]
   :  ( ( parentKey && parentKey + '.' ) || '' ) + key
  )
  .filter(key => !!key)
}

function main() {
 console.log(schemaAttributes.concat(extractKeysRecursively(myDocument)))
}
```

Lemme know you need some extra help (:

Comment: This code doesn't print the expected result that I have in the original post.

Comment: I've edited to flat the arrs in the end, take a look bro

Comment: Still does not work. It doesn't include any of the values that have indexes greater than 0. For example it does not include `friends.1.addresses.1.country` or `friends.1.addresses` or `friends.1`, etc, etc.

Comment: Also adding flat to the end does nothing to the end result. I'd suggest trying to run your code to see what the output actually is before making blind guesses. There is no nested array's in the original output of your code.

Comment: There's no nested because I've already loop through flatMap, I've tried run here only with the concat of the previous attributes and it worked, you must be missing something and messing with your code bro

Comment: Here. I just edited your answer to add the required parts to have it run in the browser. You can click the `Run code snippet` button and see that the output doesn't match the expected output.

Comment: And yes. There is no nested. So flattening the array will do absolutely nothing.